# MEF and ICommand

Tags: wpf, binding, command, mef

i have some problems with commands.
For example. I have `Workspace` with a menu. In menu I importing `IMenuItem` whitch contain ICommand.
So to make it work i have to create a `CommandBinding` in my `Workspace`.

Now, to import some `DataTemplate` i'm exporting `ResourceDictionary` and merging it with `App.Resources`, so it's  not very good at all, but it's even not applicable for `DataBinding`s.

I want to use `CommandManager` but i don't know how to, I can't find any example.

Also i want to ask is there any way to export not class, but export a values for existing class, I do not mean `MetaData`.
Cause for each `ICommand`, `IMenuItem` etc i have to declare new class

```
[Export(typeof(RoutedUICommand)]
class MyNewCommand : RoutedUICommand
{

    public MyNewCommand()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```